# Copying multiple components from another webform?

Tags: webforms

I have a bunch of webforms, threre are a lot of repeating fields just in different order or with different conditionals / labels. I want some plugin that would allow me to copy elements from existing webform to new one.

Is there such thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Webform Template](https://drupal.org/project/webform_template):

This module allows to easily copy webform configuration from one node to another (including all webform fields). If I remember well it copies all fields, you can't select wich fields to copy.

I've used it and worked fine.

EDIT: Adding more info:

The module doesn't allow you select which fields are going to be copied. Anyway, the module's code not long and it may be easy to add this funcionality. The module also triggers some cusom hook to modify webform (hook_webform_template_insert and hook_webform_template_update).

I think this would be a good starting point.

The heavy lifting seems to be done in the webform_template_node_update (hook_node_update).

```
// Insert the components into the database.
if (isset($node->webform['components']) && !empty($node->webform['components'])) {
  foreach ($node->webform['components'] as $cid => $component) {
    $component['nid'] = $node->nid;
    webform_component_insert($component);
  }
}

// Insert emails.
if (isset($node->webform['emails']) && !empty($node->webform['emails'])) {
  foreach ($node->webform['emails'] as $eid => $email) {
    $email['nid'] = $node->nid;
    webform_email_insert($email);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've seen it, it allows to copy *whole* webform, but I need element selector. Not just copy everything.

Comment: Yes I know, but is the only module, AFAIK, that copies webform element form one webform to another. You may add a new feature request in the module's issue queue asking for this functionality or even modify module by your own and post the patch to the issue queue. Answer edited with added info about how module works.

Comment: I didn't find any solutions so I'm starting my own module from scratch.

Comment: Have you evaluted modifing Webform Template? Is better to add functionality to a similar module than start a new one from scratch. May be your functionality doesn't fit in this module but is worth to check it, I think.

Comment: I thought about it, but functionality doesn't intersect much actually so new module.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the [Node clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) module

> The clone module allows users to make a copy of an existing item of site content (a node) and then edit that copy. The authorship is set to the current user, the menu and url aliases are reset, and the words "Clone of" are inserted into the title to remind you that you are not editing the original content.